# TCPDFのMultiCellの改行について

Tags: php, pdf

WEBアプリケーションからPDFで帳票を出力させようとしています。 
テンプレートを読み込んで、その上に追記するため、 
FPDI(ver 1.6.0) + TCPDF(ver 6.2.12)の組み合わせで出力しています。

MultiCellで長文を出力する際に、文字列が一塊として出るように自動調整され、 
中途半端に改行したくてもできません。 
　　※２行分しか表示できる幅がないため、横幅で可能な限り表示できるようにしたい。

例：全角9文字まで出力できるセルに【 あいうえお かきくけこ さしすせそ 】を出力する際 
　　▼表示したい内容 
　　　　あいうえお かきく
　　　　けこ さしすせそ 
　　▼実際 
　　　　あいうえお 
　　　　かきくけこ 
　　　　さしすせそ
　　　　　　※三行目は見えない

```
//表示処理 
$target= 'あいうえお かきくけこ さしすせそ'; 
$cell_w = 45; 
$cell_h = 12; 
$this->Receipt->MultiCell($cell_w, $cell_h, $target, 1, 'L', 0, 0, $col, $row, true, 0, false, true, $cell_h, 'M', false);
```

どうすれば自動調整をなくせるでしょうか？ 
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは。

確かにテストしてみると同じような現象が起きますね。
あいうえお・・・といった文字列以外にもテストしましたが、正しくスペースを表示したり改行したりと曖昧な結果になってしまいました。

解決策としては、MultiCellの引数でHtmlモードをオンにして、スペースの代わりにお馴染みの`&nbsp;`を使うことで解決しました。お試しください。

```
$targetHtml = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $target) // Html形式に変換

$cell_w = 45; 
$cell_h = 12; 

//12番目の引数をfalseからtrueに
$this->Receipt->MultiCell($cell_w, $cell_h, $targetHtml, 1, 'L', 0, 0, $col, $row, true, 0, true /* ishtml=true */ , true, $cell_h, 'M', false);
```

Comment: 返答遅れて申し訳ありません。
試してみたところ、想定どおりの動作をすることができました。
ありがとうございます！